# CGPointMake in Respect to other UIImageViews

Tags: game-design, iphone, objective-c

I have a `UIImageView` called `hitBox`, and another image called `mainSprite`. So what I want to do is when an `IBAction` is pressed, it will move `hitBox` to above `mainSprite`. I don't know if this is syntax but this is what I know moves things on the screen.

```
hitBox.center = CGPointMake(x coordinate, y coordinate);
```

I just want to replace `x` coordinate and `y` coordinate with something that will place it somewhere in relation `mainSprite`.

Comment: is your mainsprite a sprite.

Comment: Woeful lack of research here.

Answer (score 2):

Why not `hitBox.center=mainSprite.center` ?

[edit]

```
hitBox.center= CGPointMake(mainSprite.center.x,mainSprite.center.y+5);
```

Comment: No i mean like 5 pixels above it. Not over it. could i do hitBox.center = mainSprite.center+5

Comment: You can't add 5 to a CGPoint, I've edited my answer to show you how you do this.